# Complex Numbers: complex slope of a line and associated problem

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> If the line $z\overline\alpha + \overline z\alpha + i\beta = 0$ makes an angle of $45^\circ$ with the real axis, the value of $(1+i)(-\frac {2\alpha} {\overline\alpha})$ is
>
> **a)** $2\sqrt2$
>
> **b)** $2\sqrt2 i$
>
> **c)** $2(1-i)$
>
> **d)** $-2(1+i)$

**My attempt:**

The complex slope of the line is $-\frac{\alpha}{\overline \alpha}$. This is equal to $e^{i\frac \pi 4}$ as it makes an angle of $45^\circ$. Substituting this in the expression gives 
$$2(1+i)e^{i\frac \pi 4} = 2\sqrt2 e^{i\frac \pi 2} = 2\sqrt{2} i$$

which corresponds to option **b**. However, my textbook gives **c** as the answer. Please verify if my solution is correct or if it is an error in the textbook.

Comment: The vector $\alpha$ is orthogonal to the line, thus, $\arg\alpha=-\pi/4$ or $\pi-\pi/4$. It makes $$-\frac{\alpha}{\bar\alpha}=-e^{i(-\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4})}=i.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your solution is that, if the line makes an angle of $45°$ with the real axis doesn't imply that the complex slope is $e^{\frac{iπ}{4}}$.

Let's keep it simple. Let $z=x+iy$. So, given equation can be written as, 
$\begin{align}
\bar{a}(x+iy)+a(x-iy)+ib=0\\
x(\bar{a}+a)+yi(\bar{a}-a)+ib=0
\end{align}$

Now, slope of this line is 
$\begin{align}
-\frac{c.e\,of\,x}{c.e\,of\,y}&=-\frac{\bar{a}+a}{i(\bar{a}-a)}=tan\frac{π}{4}\\
\therefore -\frac{a}{\bar a}&=i
\end{align}$

After substituting in the required expression, we get, 
$$2(i-1)$$ According to me, none of the options is matching or there may be correction in option $C$.